# How to pin ssl certificate when use python+requests to acess one special web site?

Tags: ssl, https, python-requests

How to pin ssl certificate when use python+requests to acess one special web site?
I don't mean verify certificate, I mean ssl-pinning with requests library for one special site . e.g:  https://example.com

Comment: https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification

Comment: Pinning to a specific certificate or public key is not supported by requests. Pinning to a specific CA can easily be achieved by only providing the specific CA inside the `verify` argument. So the question is - what exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: Pity. I want to pin to a specific certificate.  What a pity